# Product Image Gallery Not Displaying When Using Custom Theme

Tags: product-images, luma-theme, custom-theme

I have created a child theme from Luma and when I enable it the product image gallery does not appear. When I re-enable the Luma theme the image gallery works fine. What am I missing?

NOTE: I'm using Single Store Mode

[image]